# Adapting Selenium Script for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

**Preface: I have very limited experience with linux and selenium in general. Also this is a multipart question.**

Hi there,

I've written a script that I want to run on my Raspberry Pi model 3B which is running Raspbian OS.
I originally built it on a Windows machine (pretty stupid mistake to build it for the wrong platform but anyway) and now need to adapt it so it runs on the Pi.

The main thing I am concerned about is the usage of selenium and chromedriver. I have downloaded chromium-chromedriver (chromium-chromedriver 34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2 in armhf (Release)) from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/chromium-chromedriver).

**First Question**

The file downloads as a .deb which I have never seen before. It opts to install, however I have no idea where it installs as it does not give the option to install to a different directory. I've tried search for it with find, but nothing comes up. Where does it go by default in Raspbian OS?

**Second Question**

I know I will have to change some expressions because I am using chromium-chromedriver instead of chrome driver, but I am unsure which ones as I don't know selenium that well. This is the main instance here. Do I just change all instances of "Chrome" including "chrome_options" to "Chromium/chromium_options"?

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options    

chrome_options = Options()  
                chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


                #Scrape out the table information
                with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)) as driver:
```

Lastly, for the purpose of finding the process with psutil and ending it with process.kill(), the text ID of the driver in task manager should just be chromium-chromedriver.exe right?

Any and all help and advice appreciated.

Thank you all for your time.

L